# GEE Published Application not Working?

Tags: google-earth-engine, publishing

I have a script for an application that runs perfectly fine in the Javascript API, and at one point it also ran after publication to my Earth Engine apps gallery. However, for some reason it no longer works through the link in the app gallery, even though the script is still the same and it still runs in the JS API. I have tried renewing the API key, but still no luck.

Any ideas?

```
Map.style().set({cursor: 'crosshair'});
Map.setCenter(-61.64775390624999,-5.435884044248108,6)

// Grab the latest GLAD image for your region of interest
var glad_ic = ee.ImageCollection("projects/glad/alert/UpdResult")
print(glad_ic)
var latest = ee.Image(glad_ic.filterMetadata('system:index','contains','SA').toList(400).get(-1)).select(['alertDate19']);

var coords = []
var counter = ee.Number(0)
function handleMapClick(location) {
  coords.push([location.lon, location.lat]);
  Map.addLayer(ee.Geometry.Point([location.lon, location.lat]),{},'clicked point')
  counter.add(1)
}

//Apply it to the app
Map.onClick(handleMapClick)

//Add run button
var button_run = ui.Button('Run analysis');
button_run.onClick(function(){
  Map.clear()
  get_alerts();
  Map.add(panel);
})

var button_clear = ui.Button('Clear');
button_clear.onClick(function(){
  clearResults();
})

var panel = ui.Panel([button_run, button_clear],ui.Panel.Layout.flow("horizontal"))

Map.add(panel);


function clearResults(){
  coords = []
  Map.clear()
  Map.setCenter(-61.64775390624999,-5.435884044248108,6)
  Map.add(panel);
  Map.onClick(handleMapClick);
}


function get_alerts(){  
  // Get the julian day value for one month prior to today and set all values to 1
  var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon({
    coords: coords
  })

    // Get area raster
  var area = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(10000).clip(geometry);

  // Get primary forest layer and wdpa
  var primary_forests = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection("UMD/GLAD/PRIMARY_HUMID_TROPICAL_FORESTS/v1").toList(1).get(0)).clip(geometry);
  var wdpa = ee.Image('users/BR_dcassiday/wdpa_hi_res_final').clip(geometry);

  var one_month = ee.Number.parse(ee.Date(new Date()).format('DD')).subtract(30);
  var glad = latest.where(latest,1);

  // Get weighted input raster 
  var weights = primary_forests.add(wdpa).multiply(area);

  // Get bounding rectangle
  var bounds = geometry.bounds();
  var flat_coords = bounds.coordinates().flatten();

  // Select grid size
  var grid_size = 0.1;

  // Create sequences of latitudes and longitudes
  var lat_seq = ee.List.sequence(flat_coords.get(1),flat_coords.get(5), grid_size);
  var lon_seq = ee.List.sequence(flat_coords.get(0),flat_coords.get(2), grid_size);

  // Make the grid feature collection
  var make_grid = function(i){
    i = ee.Number(i)
    var corners = lat_seq.map(function(j){
      j = ee.Number(j);
      var coords = [i,j,i.add(grid_size),j.add(grid_size)];
      var cell = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(coords).intersection(geometry));
      return cell
    })
    return corners
  }
  var grid = ee.FeatureCollection(lon_seq.map(make_grid).flatten());

  // Get inputs and area of each grid cell
  var grid_inputs = weights.reduceRegions({
    collection: grid,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    scale: 30
  })
  var grid_area = area.reduceRegions({
    collection: grid,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    scale: 30
  })
  var glad_count = glad.reduceRegions({
    collection: grid,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    scale: 30
  })

  // Calculate scores and get top 5
  var scores = ee.Array(grid_inputs.aggregate_array('sum')).divide(grid_area.aggregate_array('sum')).multiply(glad_count.aggregate_array('sum')).toList();

  var grid_scores = grid.map(function(x){
    return x.set({index: x.id(), score:scores.get(ee.Number.parse(x.id()))})
  })

  var top_5 = scores.sort().reverse().slice(0,5);
  //print(top_5)

  // Filter top five from feature collection
  var top_grid = grid_scores.filter(ee.Filter.inList('score',top_5))
  //print(top_grid)

  // Add layers to map
  //Map.addLayer(grid)
  Map.centerObject(top_grid,8)
  Map.addLayer(wdpa.updateMask(wdpa), {min:0, max:1, palette: 'purple'}, 'WDPA')
  Map.addLayer(primary_forests.updateMask(primary_forests), {min:0, max:1, palette: 'green'}, 'Primary Forests')
  Map.addLayer(top_grid, {}, 'Grid')
  Map.addLayer(glad.updateMask(glad).clip(geometry), {palette: 'pink'}, 'GLAD')
}
```

Comment: Can you share your script as a link? The code you posted doesn't work with error about get_alerts() function. Did you try deleting the published app and trying to publish again?

Comment: Hi, here is a link to my script https://code.earthengine.google.com/50be642a2b44e6865e67a39b20b2c195

Comment: I have tried publishing the code in a separate application, with a new API key. Still no luck... It worked fine at one point, and still works from the JS API

Answer (score 0):

Your [published script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/50be642a2b44e6865e67a39b20b2c195) contains an error

```
 var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon({
    coords: coords
  })
```

The coords contain lat/lon of only 1 point. You cannot construct a polygon with a single point, so the script fails and so would the app. See the error screenshot
[image]

Comment: Hi, the script is supposed to allow the user to add multiple points and create a polygon from them. The above error would happen if the user only draws two points, but it still happens if I draw 3 or 10.